# Forecast and errors, dependent or independent

Tags: time-series, forecasting

Assume the demand follows an MA(1):

$$d_t=c+e_t-\theta e_{t-1},$$

Apply now, SES(single exponential smoothing)as a forecasting method.  We know that the demand, $d_t$ is not independent. I was wondering if the forecasts and errors (demand-forecast) are  also not independent?

Comment: Yes, the forecasts and errors are not independent, but it would be good to know why do you think this is important?

Comment: but why ? it's important for me because, I applied aggregation approach with aggregation level m(m=2,...) to my basic data and then I applied SES to aggregated data to obtain one period ahead forecast; now I want to compare the variance of forecast error of aggregated demand with basic demand. in aggregated approach I have the forecasts and then error for m period and I can not compare them directly to basic data, therefore I have to divide the aggregated forecast or forecast error by m to be comparable with basic or nonaggregated one..

Comment: I think the the errors must be independent to be able to divide them by m.